# How to change image in Content Editor webpart on page refresh?

Tags: 2007

We need to change the image in a Content Editor web part when a page is refreshed.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible because there is no CSOM support in SharePoint 2007. However, you can develop a [custom field control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650791.aspx) based on RichHtmlField to accomplish this.